# Autopopulate existing specflow steps

Tags: bdd, specflow

when am trying to add new steps, I want to check whether there are related steps exists in the repository.
Is there an away to automatically populate the existing specflow steps based on keywords?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include more information about the problem? Which IDE are you using? How is it configured? SpecFlow has an extension for Visual Studio that provides exactly this behavior, so I'm curious to know why this isn't working for you.

Comment: See the SpecFlow documentation about IDE integration: https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks. I was not using the extension.

Comment: Ok, yeah. You will need to use the extension.